Are gate-checked bags screened for items not allowed in the hold?
Hand luggage and hold luggage are both screened. With regard to dangerous goods different rules apply to both. At the gate, if the cabin bins are full and passengers are permitted to put their hand luggage down in the hold, are these bags rescreened for lighters, lithium batteries or powerbanks? These are allowed to be carried on but due to the fire risk not allowed in the hold.

"Why are lithium batteries allowed on planes anyway?" because literally everyone wants to travel with them?

"Why are lithium batteries allowed on planes anyway?" because you'd be grumpy if they told you to leave your [cell phone/laptop/tablet/just about every electronic device you own] at home.

Related: Forbes reports the FAA reckons that lithium battery fires in hand luggage have risen from 9 in 2014, to 62 in 2022.

Yes, in general when you agree to gate-check your roll-a-board, they are supposed to ask if you have any vital medications, id, any electronics, and so on, and get you to remove them and squeeze them somehow into your "personal item" which you are still taking on board.
Do they always do this? No. We all have stories about them forgetting to ask. But it is what they are supposed to do and what they usually do.

I've gate checked my bag ~6 times on domestic US flights and was never asked anything.

@JonathanReez I have also never been asked.  US domestic and Canada to US

I'm not a gate-checker myself, but I have heard others asked in that rote voice "are-there-any-medications-valuables-or-electronics in this bag?"

Also have had bags gate-checked at a number of occasions. Never was I asked anything about the contents of the bag.

I’ve never heard this explicitly asked, even on long-haul flights I’ve been on, but in almost every case when I’ve flown I’ve also not seen anybody gate check things unless the gate agent announced a request that things be gate checked, and such requests have always mentioned that this stuff needs to be taken care of before gate checking a bag, so there may also be some assumption that people who are gate checking know that they need to pull this stuff out beforehand.

There is definitely an increased assumption that people know what to travel with. Even when checking bags at counters or online/baggage-drop, the questions are rushed through and tokenistic, compared to in the olden days when they seemed seriously interested in the answers.

get you to remove them and squeeze them somehow into your "personal item" which often involves removing some items from said "personal item" and putting them into the checked bag and/or pants/coat pockets.

As a data point, I once accidentally checked my bag with a lithium battery in it (I think they asked and I thought it was in my personal item). I realized it before the flight left the gate, so they found my bag and had me take the battery out. I don't know what would have happened if we were on the runway, much less in the air.
